# Sql where clause not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, qsqlquery

SQL where clause is not working in my database.

I have a table called "sites" and structure like that

```
id     site
1      xyz.com
2      google.com
3      example.com
```

I am running this SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM `sites` WHERE `site` = "google.com";
```

But I am getting this output

```
 MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0009 sec)
```

I never see before like that in my life.

Update: Screenshot

I do not want to apply this query in project.

```
SELECT * FROM `sites` WHERE `site` LIKE "%google.com%";
```

[image: Table]

```
#
```

[image: Query]

---

The real problem was in `insert` commands on creation of DB.
Try

```
INSERT INTO sites (id, site) VALUES (1, '\nxyz.com\n'), (2, '\ngoogle.com\n'), (3, '\nexample.com\n')
```

and manually check records in the table. You would not see line breaks. This is an issue in SQL I've noticed.

Comment: There is not any space i checked in table many time.

Comment: Did you tried with single quotes? `'` (`'google.com'`)

Comment: Double or single quotes dont matter for mysql

Comment: Yes i try already both not working.

Comment: Please provide me solution if possible instead negative Flags. You can test it in your server. Really not working. I am not so poor in programming.

Comment: Can you show some sample data on that column?Maybe even a screenshot

Comment: You might also try `WHERE TRIM(site) = "google.com"`

Comment: i added screenshots.

Comment: As a last resort redo it, `UPDATE sites SET Site='google.com' WHERE id=1`

Comment: @Mihai - I have try WHERE TRIM(site) = "google.com" But not working.

Comment: or `WHERE site = "google.com" COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: @Mihai - Yes i just tested it but not working.

Comment: I have also tested this issue in other two server but same problem. Really I never see like that in my life.

Comment: @Mihai -- i have changed Collation to utf 8 But not working.

Comment: I don't think you can use `TRIM` in the `WHERE` clause, it needs to be in `SELECT`

Comment: @EternalHour - i already tested using WHERE TRIM(site) = "google.com";

Comment: I don't think it will work that way.

Comment: I notice that when i remove 'dot' between google and com and then apply (Where 'site' = 'googlecom';). it's working perfectly. So here main problem is dot between google and com. I think Sql developer do not like Google with a dot com. Any answer for this update.

Comment: @EternalHour - can you please send me query. it's not so large. If you know solution.

Comment: Thank you all for support me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE: OP had invisible newline characters (\n) in his dataset.  @EternalPoster (and I) supposed that Trim would remove *all whitespace*, but [MySql Trim Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) specifies leading & trailing **spaces only**.

---

This is what I did:

```
-- for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203169/sql-query-not-work-for-google-com
-- and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202157/sql-where-clause-not-working

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

-- --------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sites`;

--
--  structure for table `sites`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sites` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- data for table `sites`
--
INSERT INTO `sites` (`id`, `site`) VALUES
(1, 'xyz.com'),
(2, 'google.com'),
(3, 'example.com');

--
-- select google
--
SELECT * 
FROM sites 
WHERE site = 'google.com'
;

--
-- select google
--
SELECT * 
FROM sites 
WHERE site = 'google.com'
;
```

and this is what I got:

[image: Script Functions As Expected]

So in my case, I see the script functioning as expected.

What's different about your case?
My installation is a fairly default setup.
The fact that `Like '%google.com%'` works on your dataset suggests a couple things.  Folks have already suggested `TRIM`, because the Like expression would match invisible characters (spaces, tabs, backspaces, nulls).  MySQL has a separate operator [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) for regular expressions, so it wouldn't seem to be that  the `.` character is being used as a wildcard, but that might be worth a look.

Create an empty database and try running my script above.  Do you get the same result I do?

Comment: I found issue. I export sql file see what >> INSERT INTO `sites` (`id`, `site`) VALUES
(1, '\nxyz.com\n'),
(2, '\ngoogle.com\n'),
(3, '\nexample.com\n');

Comment: Try this sql query **INSERT INTO sites (id, site) VALUES (1, '\nxyz.com\n'), (2, '\ngoogle.com\n'), (3, '\nexample.com\n');** And manually check in table. you can not find space or line break. That is a issues in sql i noticed.

Answer (score 2):

use this query

```
select * from sites where site = 'google.com';
```

Comment: select * from sites where site like 'google.com';  Replace '=' operator with like key word

Answer (score 1):

**My first answer:**

Use single quotes, `SELECT * FROM`sites`WHERE`site`= 'google.com';`

In regards to the single/double quote syntax, it depends on your SQL Mode. From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html):

> The ANSI_QUOTES mode causes the server to interpret double-quoted
>   strings as identifiers. Consequently, when this mode is enabled,
>   string literals must be enclosed within single quotation marks. They
>   cannot be enclosed within double quotation marks. The server SQL mode
>   is controlled as described in Section 5.1.6, “Server SQL Modes”.

**My second answer after OP's edit:**

After seeing the screenshots, it looks like you have a blank line above the URL's in your database or whitespace. You'll need to remove it manually or with [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim).

To test if there is whitespace, you can use a wildcard:

```
SELECT `site` FROM `sites` WHERE `site` LIKE '%google.com%'
```

If you get a result you know there's whitespace. if you want to workaround the issue without permanently removing the whitespace:

```
SELECT TRIM(site) FROM `sites` WHERE `site` LIKE '%google.com%'
```

To permanently remove the whitespace from only one row:

```
UPDATE `sites` SET `site` = TRIM(site) WHERE `site` LIKE '%google.com%'
```

To permanently remove the whitespace from all rows (**backup table first**), you can do:

```
UPDATE `sites` SET `site` = TRIM(site)
```

Comment: No there is not space or line. I have double checked. Can you please test this issue in your server.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use singe quotes as described in the mysql [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/selecting-columns.html). Have a look at the last example.
Besides, you should get rid of the `` around `site`

```
SELECT *
FROM `sites`
WHERE site = 'google.com';
```

Comment: Not working and (attribute site into ``) does not matter

Comment: Very strange... could you try to use the LIKE operator instead of = ? Check out here: [SQL LIKE Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `sites` WHERE `site` = 'google.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

> use this

```
select * from tb_name where col_name1 = 'your_value1' and col_name2 = 'your_value2'
```

Comment: using my query i get the data so it's working & other wise u can use `SELECT * FROM sites WHERE site LIKE  'google.com'`

Comment: But try using these data. just enter id - 1 and site - google.com and then apply same query. You can point this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Backup your data and install a fresh setup of your mysql...it might have been corrupted

Comment: I am doing this in my VPS Hosting instead localhost.

Comment: And also tested in two other server. You can try too.

Comment: In your case...the picture you have provided of phpmyadmin table....the sites coulumn is not showing its values normally...i guess extra spaces or enters are being inserted with google.com...
Try php "TRIM" function...Insert new values with the help of TRIM function.
like this
<?php
$query="insert into sites values (1,'stackexchange.com')";
$query=trim($query);
mysqli_query($query);
This might work
?>

Comment: if this works... that means previously inserted data must have some error in it