# How to do an equality comparison in a MySQL WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I have this piece of code

```
$player = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Player` WHERE `LogOn` ? `GAME`")
or die(mysql_error());
```

My issue is where I placed question mark, I need to have it so it would be Login is equal to GAME. I probably would of found the answer by searching the web, but I lack the English words.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql where clause not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202157/sql-where-clause-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need:

```
SELECT * FROM `Player` WHERE `LogOn` = 'GAME'
```

You can use upper() for case insensitive check:

```
SELECT * FROM `Player` WHERE upper(LogOn) = 'GAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `=` to check for string equality.

```
SELECT * FROM `Player` WHERE `LogOn` = 'GAME'
```

Please note `'` for string quotes in mysql.